# Fast grouping of a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of a couple thousand strings

```
['7/21/2011', '7/21/2011', '7/21/2011', '7/20/2011', etc]
```

I am currently, running this code to group by the string and get the max group value:

```
var max = 0;
var group = {};
arr.map(function (value) {
  if (group[value]) {
    group[value]++;
  } else {
    group[value] = 1;
  }
  max = Math.max(max, group[value]);
});
```

Are there any improvements to make this code run faster?

**EDIT:** 
**The results are in: http://jsperf.com/javascript-array-grouping2**

EDIT EDIT: that test was flawed. **Mike Samuel**'s code was the fastest.

6000 entries test -> http://jsperf.com/javascript-array-grouping2

10K entries test -> http://jsperf.com/javascript-array-grouping

Comment: Sounds like a job for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Sebastian, Sorry, still new to asking questions? Can I migrate it myself?

Comment: @Joey: I see a couple of good answers below. You could try them out using jsperf.com - I'd be curious to see the results

Comment: @Joey: If you wish to migrate, you can flag for moderator attention, but it looks like the question worked fine here. :) Up to you, really.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're sure this is a hotspot and speed is really important, I would try to cut out several thousand function calls by inlining `max` and `map`.

You can also make the body of your function faster by cutting out a comparison.

```
var max = 0;
var group = {};
for (var i = arr.length; --i >= 0;) {
  var value = arr[i];
  var n = group[value] = 1 - -(group[value] | 0);
  if (n > max) { max = n; }
}
```

The best thing to do is measure on the browsers you care about.

Comment: why `1 - - x` instead of `1 + x`?

Comment: Just me being silly.  `1 - - x` is unambiguously a numeric operation while `1 + x` could be string concatenation if x is not nullish, boolean, or numeric.  It's an unnecessary distinction in this case though since `(x | 0)` is guaranteed to be numeric so there's no chance of a string concatenation happening.

Answer (score 3):

Yes certainly. I would calculate the max last, instead of every iteration, and not use an if:

```
var group = {};
arr.map(function (value) {
    group[value] = (group[value] || 0) + 1;
});

var max = 0;
for (key in group) {
    if (group[key] > max) max = group[key];
}
```

EDIT: As Mike Samuel says you *might* get faster by using an index instead of map:

```
var group = {};
var max = 0;

for (var i = arr.length; --i >= 0;) {
    group[value] = (group[value] || 0) + 1;
}
for (key in group) {
    if (group[key] > max) max = group[key];
}
```

Comment: @Joey: The second loop goes over the grouped results and (depending on the input) will loop over a lot less elements.

Answer (score 2):

I think it really depends on the JS engine that you will run this code on. An alternative I think it's worth a shot is using

```
n = group[value] = (group[value]||0) + 1;
if (n > max) max = n;
```

for each element.

I also think that may be using a regular loop can be faster because the variables you will use will be just locals and not closed-over variables of a closure (that are normally slower) and you will also save a function call per element. Both those problems are non-issues if the implementation can inline this closure, but I don't know if there are JS implementations smart enough for that.